# adding a listener for a Linked List or any kind of list

Tags: java

I have a linked list and I just want to listen for any changes like something being added to the linked list.

What is the best way to this?

Comment: a quick look into the api doc would have revealed ... no such method :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the list into an *observable list* (something you'd have to write).

```
public class ObservableList implements List<T> {
  private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
  // usual methods for adding/removing listeners

  private List<T> list;
  public ObservableList(List<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }

  // implement methods from List and delegate to the internal list
  // send notifications to listeners for add/remove operations

  public boolean add(T item) {
    fireEvent(Type.ADD, item);  // like that
    return list.add(item);      // delegate to the internal list
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like java should have some type of listener already built that you can override if you wants. Thanks pretty lame.

Comment: Start your IDE and you have it implemented in less then 15 minutes. What's the problem? Downloading a lib and learning how to use it takes more time.

Answer (score 3):

You might try an ObservableCollection.

See:

http://commons.apache.org/dormant/events/apidocs/org/apache/commons/events/observable/ObservableCollection.html

Answer (score 0):

I would implement my own list and in the add method have it call another method which "notifies" you of the change. I've never done that before, so I can't give you an example (maybe someone else could), but it shouldn't be to complicated. Give it a shot.