# How to refresh text in a TextArea in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a really simple chat in Java and I have a doubt. If you check the GUI [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYlTq.png), you will see that I have a button to refresh messages. However, I would like that everytime a message is send from any user, every of them refresh their messages to check for new ones. How can I do it without the button?

Here is the code of the GUI:

```
    private JPanel Panel;
    private JTextField Mensaje;
    private JButton Enviar_Grupo;
    private JButton Enviar_Usuario;
    private JTextPane Mensajes_Directos;
    private JTextPane Mensajes_Grupo;
    private JLabel usuarios;
    private JLabel grupo;
    private JButton Recargar;
    private JLabel Usuario;
    private JTextField Usuario_Enviar;

    Pantalla(String titulo, Colega colega, ArrayList<Colega> colegitas){
        super(titulo);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setContentPane((Panel));
        this.pack();

        Usuario.setText("Chat de " + colega.getID());

        Enviar_Grupo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String mensaje = Mensaje.getText();
                colega.comunicar_grupal(mensaje);
            }
        });

        Enviar_Usuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String mensaje = Mensaje.getText();
                String usuario_envio = Usuario_Enviar.getText();
                usuario_envio = Usuario_Enviar.getText();
                Boolean no_enviado=true;

                for(int i=0;i<colegitas.size();i++){
                    if(colega.getID() != colegitas.get(i).getID()) {
                        if (usuario_envio.equals(colegitas.get(i).getID())) {
                            if (((colegitas.get(i).getRol() == 1) && (colega.rol == 1)) || (colegitas.get(i).getRol() == 0)){
                                colega.comunicar_individual(mensaje, colegitas.get(i));
                                Usuario_Enviar.setText("Mensaje Enviado...");
                                no_enviado = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(no_enviado==true){
                    Usuario_Enviar.setText("Mensaje no enviado (Admin o no encontrado).");
                }
            }
        });
        Recargar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String mensajes_indi=new String();
                String mensajes_grupales=new String();

                for(int j = 0; j<colega.get_mensajes_individuales().size(); j++) {
                    mensajes_indi = mensajes_indi + colega.get_mensajes_individuales().get(j) + "\n";
                }
                for(int j = 0; j<colega.get_mensajes_grupales().size(); j++) {
                    mensajes_grupales=mensajes_grupales+colega.get_mensajes_grupales().get(j)+"\n";
                }
                Mensajes_Directos.setText(mensajes_indi);
                Mensajes_Grupo.setText(mensajes_grupales);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYlTq.png)
[image]

Comment: I am guessing this is using Swing - you might add the import statements so people are sure about the UI library being used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have somewhere in the server side a list of message ?
If yes then you could use a listener connect to that list in client side and then refresh the tchat on it.

To add a listener to your list you can do it as there

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685844/14631359